# Multiple new posts using XML-RPC?

Tags: xml-rpc

Is it possible to create multiple posts in one XML-RPC request?
I've searched everywhere, but did not find any info. I suppose it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer? **No.**

There is a finite list of methods exposed by the XML-RPC interface, and the ones that allow you to create new posts dictate that you create one post at a time.

Given, you could always write your own method to allow for bulk post creation, but you should [ask a new question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you want to go that route.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can extend XML-RPC, but the idea here was to do this without any development on the WP side. Too bad, we can't do that. Btw, as I know, wordpress doesn't even have any function to create multiple posts "locally", am I correct? I did not find any function for this.

Comment: Correct. The closest you will come is the WordPress importer which is, itself, a plugin.  In any case, your best bet is to just loop through the posts and make multiple calls to the XML-RPC new post method.